# Responsive image rollover transitions in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several thumbnails, each containing an image and a caption. I had previously used `opacity` to fade between a black and white and a colour version of the image on `:hover`, but this no longer works now that I have converted the images to `img-responsive` in Bootstrap 3, due to it requiring `position: absolute`.

I managed to get it to work using the `-webkit-filter: grayscale` effect instead of two images but obviously this only works in compatible browsers. Is there any way of achieving this in a cross-browser compliant way?

Currently the code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="thumbnail-image">
<!-- <img src="images/BW.png" class="img-responsive" alt="(Black & White)" /> -->
<img src="images/Colour.png" class="img-responsive" alt="(Colour)" />
</div>
<div class="caption">
<h3>Thumbnail</h3>
<p>Thumbnail caption.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.thumbnail-image img {
transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-image img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to this problem after a few months and I found this to be the most conclusive answer:

http://labs.voronianski.com/css3-grayscale/

```
.grayscale { 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS to get it working in IE7-9.

```
.thumbnail-image img {
transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1)';
filter:progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1);
}

.thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-image img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
-ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=0)';
filter:progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=0);
}
```